# CasperJS screenshots returning blank

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have a CasperJS script I am trying to run and take screenshots, but it seems to only ever open 'about:blank' when run.

Below is a link to the script I am trying to use if anyone can tell me where I am going wrong,

thanks.

http://jsbin.com/ujuret/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me if I remove `url` from screenshot filename. I replaced:

```
this.capture(savePath + "/"+ url + breakpoints[currentBreakpoint - 1][0] + ".png");
```

with:

```
this.capture(savePath + "/" + breakpoints[currentBreakpoint - 1][0] + ".png");
```

and got 3 files for different resolution.

It seems you need to escape `url` properly before using it as a part of a filename.